# Symfony Form Builder - custom attribute with option value

Tags: php, symfony, formbuilder, bootstrap-select, symfony5

i'm using bootstrap-select to create some form selects generated in form builder. I need to make custom option with some html tags inside and for this i need to make custom attribute called `data-attribute` with content equals to option content. I made in Entity new property `choiceLabel` returning date and title with html

`return '<span style="color: #A50911">'.(($this->getDate())? $this->getDate()->format("Y-m-d"): null). '</span> ' . $this->getTitle();`

This is connected with `choice_label` in form : `'choice_label' => 'choiceLabel'`

Is there any possibility to use this in attr property?

```
'attr' => [
   "data-content" => 'choiceLabel'
]
```

Something like that (this is what i mean)

HTML equivalent in twig (other form without builder):

```
<option value="{{ event.id??null }}" class="option-text" data-content="<span style='color: #A50911'>{{ event.date|date('Y-m-d') }}</span> {{ event.name }}"><span style='color: #A50911'{{ event.date|date('Y-m-d') }}</span> {{ event.name }}</option>
```

Solved, working code :

```
'choice_attr' => function($choice, $key, $value){
  return ['data-content' => "<span style='color: #A50911'>".((!empty($choice->getDate()))? $choice->getDate()->format("Y-m-d"): null )."</span> ".$choice->getTitle()];
},
```

Thanks to Vyctorya :)

Comment: Can you post an example of the html output you are trying to achieve? I am struggling to follow your question.

Comment: There is a similar code wihout form builder:

Comment: `<option value="{{ event.id??null }}" class="option-text" data-content="<span style='color: #A50911'>{{ event.date|date('Y-m-d') }}</span> {{ event.name }}"><span style='color: #A50911'{{ event.date|date('Y-m-d') }}</span> {{ event.name }}</option>`

Comment: If your field is a ChoiceType you can use 'choice_attr' https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-attr

Comment: Thanks Vyctorya, it work :)